# How can I open the pdf viewer directly without open the report preview?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, devexpress, xtrareport

I have a print button in my code, and when I click the button I want to open my report directly in PDF VIEWER, without to open the report preview.

Comment: what have you tried, Please provide a sample of your code and show us what you have tried so far.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but does´nt help me, because in your link the example is for asp.net not for MVC, and the report is for .NET  not for devexpress, I´ve searched in devexpress documentation, but I have found no solution. When I execute my report it´s shows correctly but with report viewer, and I want to show my report in the pdf viewer directly.

Answer (score 1):

You can create an XtraReport without showing it and still use its ExportToPdf method to save the generated report either to a file or a stream.

For instance, here I'm creating a report, saving it to a MemoryStream and then immediately loading that into the PdfViewer control without ever showing the XtraReport Preview form:

```
//Create report
XtraReport1 rep = new XtraReport1();
rep.DataSource = //your data source here

//Save to a memory stream and load into the PdfViewer
using(MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
{
    rep.ExportToPdf(ms);
    pdfViewer1.LoadDocument(ms);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I can´t find the PdfViewer control for MVC, I see in internet that this control is for ASP:NET not for MVC, is there any way that you know, to replace this control or any other solution?

Comment: My mistake, I was speaking of the WinForms suite--I did not notice the ASP.NET MVC tag applied to your question.